# How to fix file format and extension don't match?

Tags: c#, excel

I created a code in c# which creates and saves excel file. The code can successfully create and save excel file, but when I open the excel file created, it displays a warning message telling:

> The file format and extension of 'filename.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I am using the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialogSummary.Filter = "Excel Flie|*.xls";
        saveFileDialogSummary.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialogSummary.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialogSummary.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialogSummary.Title = "Export Excel File To";

        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        ExcelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewSummary.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewSummary.Rows[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = row.Cells[j].ToString();
            }
        }

        DialogResult res = saveFileDialogSummary.ShowDialog();
        if(res == DialogResult.OK){
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialogSummary.FileName);
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
```

What should I do to avoid receiving that warning message?

Comment: can you just use `CSV` format ?

Comment: There are FormatCode values for each flavour of  EXCEL file - use those and you won't have to worry about which version your client has installed.

Comment: What is this: `ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change the .xls to .xlsx if you have the latest office installed.

Comment: .xlsx doesn't even allow the file to be open, at least with .xls you are prompted to proceed or not

Answer (score 11):

I know this problem may be resolved by now, but just trying to help you without modifying the code can still use .xls format in your's and suppress this warning while opening the file by setting a registry. 
Open reg edit, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14\Excel\Security`

Create a `DWord` with name `ExtensionHardening` and set the value to 0.

This might get your system vulnerable, but it is not a big  deal when working in organisation network, at-least when you're sure of downloading the type of doc and source.

Comment: Yep. Works fine with 15 and 16 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Does this also work for 16 64bit version? I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me!  I use 32 bit Excel.  Good job!

Answer (score 3):

The file extension .xls and .xlsx file contain different-different layout. the extension .xls use in version 2003 whereas then version .xlsx extension to be used.
You must export excel file to .xlsx format. It will support in all version as i used.

**Add below DLLS into bin folder**
1. ClosedXML.dll
2. DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

**Code to Export to .xlsx**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    //Create column and inser rows
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {         
                var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, Sheetname);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + p_FileName + ".xlsx");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for "file format and extension don't match" is to close the work book**($workbook->close;)** at last after all necessary writings done on to the file.

I faced the same issue while opening the "XLS" file from mail. I created a file and inserted all my stuff init and without closing the workbook I send the mail as an attachment. Later I realized that have to close the workbook and send as an attachment.