# Processing Excel files with Perl, Office 2016 upgrade security issue

Tags: excel, perl, office-2016

I’ve installed [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) on the server and testing sample code from the documentation.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

    my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
    my $file = "/data/excel/matrix.xls";

    my $workbook = $parser->parse($file);

    if ( !defined $workbook ) {
        print "can't find workbook!!!";
        die $parser->error(), ".\n";
    }

    for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
        my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

        for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
            for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

                my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                next unless $cell;

                print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
                print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
                print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
                print "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

We’ve been just upgraded to Office 2016. The files are in the old Excel format (.xls). These files are copied from an instrument and needed to be converted to text for further processing.

The problem is that Perl doesn’t recognize the file as being Excel, unless I open it, enable content, verify that it’s trusted and re-save it.

Is there a way to bypass all these security warnings so I don’t have to open and re-save each file manually? Thanks for your advice in advance.

Please see warnings:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution using `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, but since you seem to be running this on a computer with Office installed, you do have the possibility of using `Win32::OLE` to access the documents. ... I do not have Office '16. Could you please post a screenshot of the warning you get when you open the document? [Is this the issue?](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3098898/microsoft-windows/excel-refusing-to-open-files-blame-the-kb-3115322-3115262-security-updates.html). Can you "add the source of the files to the Trusted Locations list in Excel."?

Comment: The code runs on the Linux server. I've attached some of the errors. Once I bypass the warnings and save the file the code works fine. Thanks

Comment: So where exactly is Office actually involved in this process? Is the instrument generating these files by invoking Office stuff on a Windows system? Can you, on the system where these files are generated, add the location to "Trusted Locations". See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4

Comment: The files are generated on a next generation sequencing instrument which has it's own server. Then files are transferred to another Linux server for further processing.

Comment: Then I do not see what this has to do with Office '16 ... You say "We’ve been just upgraded to Office 2016. The files are in the old Excel format (.xls)... " but if Excel is not involved at any point in the process, I don't see the relevance. What happens when you run that Perl script on one of these files?

Comment: When I run the script without opening and re-saving the .xls the script can't detect any data.  If I open and re-save the file the script works perfect.

Comment: If I understand correctly, some software (not Excel) is generating Excel files.  When you try to use your Perl script on those files, it has issues.  If you open the files in Excel and save them, then the Perl script has no issues using the Excel files.  Is that correct?  If so, it sounds like the Excel files are not being created properly and although your Perl script is having issues, Excel is able to open the files and correct the issues when saving them.  I would look at what's generating the Excel files since that appears to be the source of the problem.

Comment: The issue with the pop-up can be solved by a registry value addition - follow this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403642/how-to-fix-file-format-and-extension-dont-match

Comment: But I am also facing issues while reading Excel 2016 as my Perl script is not reading the .xls files which are externally provided neither it is throwing error. But it works when I open and save it as .xls on my system.