# Is this the Right way to Export to an Excel using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This AngularJS code works, but the problem is it shows the excel warning "This file format and extension of download.xls doesnt match", Is there a better way.

[image]

```js
// Code goes here
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope){
      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
        }
    });
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
.table-header 
{
background-color: lightskyblue;  
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js
"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Export to Excel</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableToExport')">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
 Export to Excel
    </button>
    <div id="tableToExport">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-header">
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Process Type</th>
            <th>Cedent</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>value 4</td>
            <td>value 5</td>
            <td>value 6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10.12.2015</td>
            <td>AXA Affin</td>
            <td>101024 - Quota Share QS</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix file format and extension don't match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403642/how-to-fix-file-format-and-extension-dont-match)

Comment: I advice you to google for some ready solution e.g. https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport. Switching to csv or server-side generation are also good options to consider.

Comment: try changing  uri: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Edison I tried that it says "Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"